# Error VT-x not available for Vagrant machine into a Virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, centos, vagrant, virtualbox

In my MacBook Pro I installed an ubuntu machine (64 bits) via VirtualBox.

Inside this Ubuntu machine, I installed the Vagrant to be able to create 3 VMs (VirtualBox) via command line in the terminal.

I give the "vagrant up" command to create the machines, but I get back the error message "VT-x is not available".

It seems that my device is not enabled to do virtualization, however, in the settings of my VirtualBox, everything is correct ... at least, I followed the step by step.

Is the problem on my mac? Have you seen this error? I have seen in some cases that you have to enable virtualization in BIOs, but my Ubuntu VM opens normally. I also checked out in other post that is not possible to get a VirtualBox VM inside a VirtualBox VM, is this correct?

```
#Vagrantfile

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

#DEVOPS
  config.vm.define "devops" do |devops|
    devops.vm.hostname = "devops"
    devops.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
    devops.vm.box_check_update = false
    devops.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.99.10", dns: 
"8.8.8.8"

    devops.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |dev|
    dev.memory = "4092"
   end
  end 

#DOCKER
  config.vm.define "docker" do |docker|
    docker.vm.hostname = "docker"
    docker.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
    docker.vm.box_check_update = false
    docker.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.99.20", dns: 
"8.8.8.8"

    docker.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |doc|
    doc.memory = "2048"
   end
  end 

#AUTOMATION
  config.vm.define "automation" do |automation|
    automation.vm.hostname = "automation"
    automation.vm.box = "centos/7"
    automation.vm.box_check_update = false
    automation.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.99.30", 
dns: "8.8.8.8"

    automation.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |aut|
    aut.memory = "4092"
   end
  end

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    test -d /root/.ssh/ || mkdir /root/.ssh/
    echo "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
--- PRIVATE KEY MASKED ----
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa
    echo "ssh-rsa 
---MASKED--- > /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
    chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
  SHELL
end
```

Comment: You can't run a VM from another VM in Virtualbox - VirtualBox doesn't support it.

Comment: Hi, is there any alternative? Which another VM works fine to be installed in mac and then create VMs into it?

Comment: VirtualBox actually added this feature a few days ago, but hardware support is going to be spotty at best and community support will be low due to how few people have had a chance to try it out. https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=90831. VMWare also supports nested virtualization.